# Designing Multiprocess signaling and communication

Tags: python, object-oriented, library, multiprocessing

Originally I meant to discuss my entire project on stepper motors for Raspberry Pi. But I see that's out of scope. If you'd like to provide high level feedback, welcome to do so in github.

The lack of true parallelism (multiple thread running simultaneously) due to the GIL, imposed a setback to my library as soon as I connected a second motor. PPS plummeted to roughly half. So I decided to double down and integrate `multiprocess` (**MP**)(tried `multiprocessing` 1st with poor results mainly around passing down state to child process). I'm happy with the results so far, but it did add a few extra layers of complexity to my project.

My main goal was to make it extensible by means of best OOP practices, and this multiprocess feature makes client code a bit more complicated.

**My goal here is to get feedback on my multiprocess implementation.** Dealing with low level multiprocess shared memory or queues (serialized) is a lot harder than this API (IMO), but I'd be happy to receive feedback if I can make it easier for client code to setup and use the lib.

functionality is basically:

- Starting motor drivers in Child process
- Using drivers in MainProcess as proxies (so user code does not deal with MP signaling.)
- Events (like `steppingCompleted`) propagate to MainProcess transparently.
- *toughest part for users*: Custom client shared data can **easily** be operated on. `MultiprocessObserver` intends to encapsulate `multiprocess.Event` and locking so user only sends regular callbacks with only business logic. Things like triggering user level logic or events when custom predicates become true can be done this way.

Following is a UML (ignoring structural relations) that depict MP collaboration.

[image]

Client code would have to look like this (using one motor for lenght.):

```
import ctypes
from functools import partial
from multiprocess import Value, Event

from stepper_motors_juanmf1.Controller import DRV8825MotorDriver
from stepper_motors_juanmf1.ControllerFactory import MultiProcessingControllerFactory, ControllerFactory
from stepper_motors_juanmf1.EventDispatcher import EventDispatcher, MultiprocessObserver
from stepper_motors_juanmf1.StepperMotor import PG35S_D48_HHC2


class PolarCoordinatesSample:

    """
    Initialization:
      Register even Listeners.
      Start motor driver(s) in child process.
      Setup MultiprocessObserver with publisher/observer callback pairs.
    """
    def __init__(self, controllerFactory: MultiProcessingControllerFactory):
        self.fireReadyEventsAwaited = [
            "azimuthAimingCompletesteppingCompleteAdvance",
            "azimuthAimingCompletesteppingCompleteFinalStep"
        ]
        self.azimuthDriver = None
        self.initDrivers(controllerFactory)
        EventDispatcher.instance().register(self.fireReadyEventsAwaited, self.fireReadyEventHandler)

    def initDrivers(self, controllerFactory):
        if isinstance(controllerFactory, MultiProcessingControllerFactory):
            self._initMpDrivers(controllerFactory)
        else:
            # Not used in this example.
            self._initLocalDrivers(controllerFactory)

    def _initMpDrivers(self, controllerFactory: MultiProcessingControllerFactory):
        azimuthDriverShared = Value(ctypes.c_int, 0)

        azimuthObserver = MultiprocessObserver(eventObserver=partial(self.childProcessEventObserver, "azimuth"),
                                               eventPublisher=self.sharedDataProcessing,
                                               sharedMemory=azimuthDriverShared)

        self.azimuthDriver = (controllerFactory
                .setUpProcess()
                .withDriver(multiprocessObserver=azimuthObserver,
                            factoryFnReference=controllerFactory.getMpCustomTorqueCharacteristicsDRV8825With,
                            stepperMotor=PG35S_D48_HHC2(True), directionPin=13,
                            stepPin=19, sleepGpioPin=12)
                # Can put orders to build more drivers here .withDriver(...).withDriver(...)...
                .spawn())

    def childProcessEventObserver(self, name, sharedInt):
        """
        Multiprocess event observer. Runs in parent process in dedicated Worker thread. Blocks until Events fire.
        """
        print(f"Parent process notified every {name}'s 100th step. Step: {sharedInt.value}")

    @staticmethod
    def sharedDataProcessing(sharedMemory, currentPosition):
        # Client process knows what's in sharedMemory, not Drivers.
        # Prints every 100 steps.
        print(f"Running callback from Navigation stepping in child process \n "
              f"{currentPosition, sharedMemory}")

    def _initLocalDrivers(self, controllerFactory: ControllerFactory):
        """
        Not used in multiprocess scenario. Regular Factory, simplest approach for comparison with MP approach.
        """
        self.azimuthDriver: DRV8825MotorDriver = controllerFactory.getCustomTorqueCharacteristicsDRV8825With(
            PG35S_D48_HHC2(True), directionPin=13, stepPin=19, sleepGpioPin=12)

    """
    Setup done, usage follows
    """

    def operateDrivers(self, azimuthDelta, elevationDelta):
        eventNamePrefix = "AimingComplete"
        # Events will result in 4 combinations: "[azimuth|elevation]AimingCompletesteppingComplete[Advance|FinalStep]"
        if azimuthDelta != 0:
            azimuthJob = self.azimuthDriver.signedSteps(azimuthDelta, self.steppingCallback,
                                                        jobCompleteEventNamePrefix="azimuth" + eventNamePrefix)
            self.awaitAzimuthReadyEvents()

    @staticmethod
    def steppingCallback(currentPosition, targetPosition, direction,
                         multiprocessObserver: MultiprocessObserver = None):
        """
        Called each step of the motor.
        Uses :func:`~MultiprocessObserver.eventPublisher` to notify MainProcess when custom conditions met.
        Contract:
          fn(pulsingController.controller.getCurrentPosition(),
             pulsingController.targetPosition,
             pulsingController.controller.accelerationStrategy.realDirection,
             pulsingController.controller.multiprocessObserver)  # Only provided in multiprocessing scenario. Method
                                                                 # runs in child process.
        """
        if multiprocessObserver:
            # Important, as in local process scenario sharedMemory is None. see :func:`~self._initLocalDrivers()`
            multiprocessObserver._sharedMemory.value += 1
            if multiprocessObserver._sharedMemory.value % 100 == 0:
                # every 100th step, signals Parent process to read multiprocessObserver._sharedMemory
                # eventPublisher runs `self.childProcessEventObserver()` provided callback with a lock and clears Event
                MultiprocessObserver.eventPublisher(multiprocessObserver, currentPosition)

    def awaitAzimuthReadyEvents(self):
        if not "azimuthAimingCompletesteppingComplete" in self.fireReadyEventsAwaited:
            self.fireReadyEventsAwaited.append("azimuthAimingCompletesteppingCompleteAdvance")
            self.fireReadyEventsAwaited.append("azimuthAimingCompletesteppingCompleteFinalStep")

    def fireReadyEventHandler(self, calleeId, eventInfo):
        """
        Method registered with EventDispatcher.
        @param calleeId: EventDispatcher creates a uuid for each callable you can use to unregister it.
        @param eventInfo: custom.
        @return: 
        """
        ed = EventDispatcher.instance()
        # does custom checks on eventInfo and fire App level event
        ed.publishMainLoop("MyBusinessLogicEventMotorDone", {'isReady': True})
```

Relevant objects structure.

[image]

[*full project here*](https://github.com/juanmf/StepperMotors)

Answer (score 1):

nit, typo in `PolarCoordinatesSample` docstring: "even"

I see we went with camelCase, OK.

## enum

```
        self.fireReadyEventsAwaited = [
            "azimuthAimingCompletesteppingCompleteAdvance",
            "azimuthAimingCompletesteppingCompleteFinalStep"
        ]
```

It seems slightly sad that these are of type `str`.
Using enums would e.g. ease a refactor where
we choose to capitalize "Stepping".

An enum `.value` can certainly be the same `str` we see here.

Similarly when firing `"MyBusinessLogicEventMotorDone"`

## docstring

Consider promoting the `#` comment in `sharedDataProcessing()`
to a docstring.

For that, childProcessEventObserver, and steppingCallback,
the hardcode `100` is slightly surprising.
Maybe it could be a MANIFEST_CONSTANT ?

OTOH the magic numbers in `_initLocalDrivers` look entirely reasonable.

## cost of sorting

```
    def __setitem__(self, key, value):
            ...
            self._keys.append(key)
            self._keys.sort()
```

In [SortedDict](https://github.com/juanmf/StepperMotors/blob/ef8d63b/src/stepper_motors_juanmf1/SortedDict.py)
it looks like we have quadratic cost when
constructing a new dict or submitting a big update.

The [sortedcontainers](https://pypi.org/project/sortedcontainers)
project offers some very nice datastructures
that you might choose to adopt.

## sgn

This approach in
[myMath](https://github.com/juanmf/StepperMotors/blob/ef8d63b/src/stepper_motors_juanmf1/myMath.py)
seems undesirable:

```
def sign(x):
        ...
        return x / abs(x)
```

Prefer [math.copysign(1.0, x)](https://docs.python.org/3/library/math.html#math.copysign).

BTW, I like the sanity checks you have inserted, such as these:

```
        assert not SharedManager.instance
        assert parent_process() is None
```